# Stderr and stdout interrupted randomly by newline chars in testcontainers-java

Tags: java, maven, testcontainers

I'm running Junit5 test with [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/commands/#executing-a-command), in the test I'm starting an image with Maven to execute some commands.

For example, I created a test just to print `mvn` version to stdout:

```java
        this.net = Network.newNetwork();
       
        this.clientContainer = new GenericContainer<>("maven:3.6.3-jdk-11")
            .withWorkingDirectory("/w")
            .withClasspathResourceMapping("maven-settings.xml", "/w/settings.xml", BindMode.READ_ONLY)
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .withNetwork(net)
            .withCommand("tail", "-f", "/dev/null");

        this.clientContainer.start();

        ExecResult res  =this.clientContainer.execInContainer(
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                "mvn", "-B", "-version"
            );

        System.out.println("stdout: " + res.getStdout());
```

But the output looks strange, since it has too many newline characters in stdout:

```
stdout: Apache
 M
a
v
en
 3.6.
3
 (cec
e
d
d
3
4
3
0
0
2
6
9
6
d
0
a
b
b
5
0
b
3
2
b
5
4
1
b
8
a
6
b
a
2
8
8
3
f
)


M
a
v
e
n
 
h
o
m
e
:
 
/
u
s
r
/
s
h
a
r
e
/
m
a
v
e
n


J
a
v
a
 
v
e
r
s
i
o
n
:
 
1
1
.
0
.
1
0
,
 
v
e
n
d
o
r
:
 
O
r
a
c
l
e
 
C
o
r
p
o
r
a
t
i
o
n
,
 
r
u
n
t
i
m
e
:
 
/
u
s
r
/
l
o
c
a
l
/
o
p
e
n
j
d
k
-
1
1


D
e
f
a
u
l
t
 
l
o
c
a
l
e
:
 
e
n
,
 
p
l
a
t
f
o
r
m
 
e
n
c
o
d
i
n
g
:
 
U
T
F
-
8


O
S
 
n
a
m
e
:
 
"
l
i
n
u
x
"
,
 
v
e
r
s
i
o
n
:
 
"
5
.
1
0
.
8
_
1
"
,
 
a
r
c
h
:
 
"
a
m
d
6
4
"
,
 
f
a
m
i
l
y
:
 
"
u
n
i
x
"
```

What could be the problem here? I tried to run with and without `-B` option, tried other Maven commands, and tested with specifying charset encoding.

Comment: "It works on my machine ..." (C)

Theoretically shouldn't be related to Testcontainers, unless you use some really old version.

Comment: What if you try evalutating execResult.getStdout() in the debug mode?

Comment: Is the output from plain console or from IDEA IntellIJ (output)? Furthermore the question is: Why do you like to run Maven in a JUnit 5 Test? Apart from that why do you need `tail...` command?

Comment: @khmarbaise it's same for console run `mvn verify` and idea test run. Running maven in test is my business case - I'm testing web service that can return maven artifacts. Tailf is a workaround to keep container alive until stopped (it's started in beforeEach method and each test method executes different commands)

Comment: @VitalyChura it has the same newline characters

Comment: Hm.. why not using a repo manager there any some available. OK another story. You don't need to keep the container alive because the container is a run once container. Usually used via `docker run ...`  I can acknowledge the information of yuppie-flu's answer. Furthermore I expect to keep that container running will produce issues later... If you are already using JUnit Jupiter you could start a separate container for each test case (clean/separated) and parallelize the tests via JUnit Jupiter ... I suggest to start it via BeforeEachCallback and stop the container via AfterEachCallBack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1854) of the Tescontainers library itself. However, it was fixed in the latest version `1.15.2` ([fix PR](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/3752)), so try to upgrade the Testcontainers.

I was able to reproduce your issue with `1.15.1` version, but not with `1.15.2` anymore.